# How to do (Multi-class or Multi-label) node Classification in Graph Neural Network?

Tags: multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification, mlp, gnn

I am very interested in Node Classification using GCN.

But I don't know how it can be applied when there are many types of labels in GNN.

For example, in the case of drugs, detoxification can be carried out for various diseases, so what I want is that if we proceed with the node classification of drugs, various applicable diseases will come out as a label.

To this end, we are going to proceed with multi-class classification, but since the basic label information has multiple labels, it is difficult to apply the code as a label by applying one hot encoding of [drug x label_class_num].

I would appreciate it if anyone could provide an example or give me some information for reference.

I'm also wondering if it's possible to compare with BCE whether or not that node has that disease when you pick one out of n diseases. In this case, do you need n models to separate each disease into BCE?

My experimental code is based on the code on the site below.
https://www.kaggle.com/code/naifislam/node-classification-with-gcn